# plink SSH via proxy

Tags: ssh

I can use putty to ssh to a server via my company's corporate proxy.

The two forms I fill out are session:

[image]

and proxy

[image]

Where the proxy is a HTTP proxy requiring username and password.

What is the equivalent way to create an ssh session using plink ?

Comment: What do you want to achieve? SSH using plink or use a  PuTTY saved session to login?

Comment: Hint: the second option in @SANDEEP's question is the correct one: http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/faq.html#faq-options .

Comment: I want to achieve SSH using plink - I am currently using Putty saved sessions.
The reason being that when getting non-tech savvy people to use Putty they often miss things - it would be easier in my case to get them to execute a batch file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @dave_thompson_085 has pointed out it isn't currently possible.
http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/faq.html#faq-options.

The best that can be done is using saved sessions.